# Feynman diagrams in Gaussian integrals

Tags: resource-recommendations, feynman-diagrams, wick-theorem

I am looking for suggestions for material regarding Feynman diagrams for gaussian integrals. I am looking for something of the sort of: [Pedro Vieira, Statistical Physics Applied to Quantum Field Theory, Lecture 3](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aqGne9VNTk8). I thought I understood the lecture. But then I found myself incredibly lost when I saw this lecture on Matrix Models [Pedro Vieira, Statistical Physics Applied to Quantum Field Theory, Lecture 4](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cu8-KSP3zL8). I guess I am looking for material with loads of examples!

Comment: Why do you need Feynman diagrams if the integral is Gaussian?

Comment: @octonion: OP probably means $n$-point integrals like $\int d^n x \, x_{i_1} \dots x_{i_n} e^{- |x|^2/2}$.

Comment: @HansMoleman, Yes so in your integral the Feynman diagram would just be $n/2$ unconnected lines. What's the point of using a diagram?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're looking for is in

- Chapter 1 of "Path Integrals in Quantum Mechanics" by Zinn-Justin.

Other standard texts on the topic are:

- "The Path Integral approach to Quantum Mechanics" by Ricardo Ratazzi,
- "Path Integrals in Physics: Volume I Stochastic Processes and Quantum Mechanics" by Demichev and Chaichian,
- "Field theory: a path integral approach" by Ahok Das.

A nice brief intro can be found in Chapter 14 of Schwartz.

For matrix models, just google: [one](http://uu.diva-portal.org/smash/get/diva2:731610/FULLTEXT01.pdf%22), [two](https://math.unice.fr/~patras/CargeseConference/ACQFT09_JBZuber2.pdf), etc.